# SQL Union ALL statement not reporting correct results

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have a UNION ALL that Im trying to add a new field to. I want to report on the `supplier_number` column, but currently when running my query, I am unable to include that column into the second select.
The join to this table is within the first select, but not the second select beneath the union all.
If I include the join within the second select, it reports a grossly incorrect number of records.
The field I am trying to report on is the `supplier_number` field.

```
 SELECT
  si.supplier_number AS 'supplier_number',

FROM
    items_items ii
  JOIN stock_items si ON ii.id = si.inventory_id

UNION ALL

SELECT
  '' AS 'supplier_number',

FROM
  items_items ii
  LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = ii.product_id;
```

I know right now the second supplier_number is reporting blank via the ''.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _it reports a grossly incorrect number of records_ That is rather vague. Can you put a SQLFiddle together with some test data?

Comment: ALso it owuld be useful to know what you expected from the 2 queries

Comment: Have you considered changing ii.product_id = p.id in second select join like LEFT JOIN product p ON ii.product_id= p.id;?

Comment: _grossly incorrect number of records_ suggests to me that you may be expecting a result set with a distinct list of supplier numbers; but neither of your queries use the DISTINCT clause, and your UNION goes out of it's way to include duplicates by specifying ALL.